# Errors when trying to search yahoo

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to search a query in yahoo using this code:

```py
import re
import requests

query = "deep"
yahoo = "https://search.yahoo.com/search?q=" + query
raw_page = requests.get(yahoo)
```

But I get an error like this:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'

The error happens at the last line. How can I fix this?

## Edit

This is the whole code:

```py
import re
import requests

no = 10
query = "deep"
yahoo = "https://search.yahoo.com/search?q=" + query + "&n=" + str(no)
#yahoo = "https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + query
raw_page = requests.get(yahoo) 
results = re.findall(r'(?<=<h3 class="r"><a href="/url\?q=).*?(?=&amp)', str(raw_page))
res = list(set(results))[0:30] #Provides 30 unique of the 35 we requested above

print(res)
```

and this is the error track:

[image]

Comment: I don't see how that error is possible.  Please edit the question to include the full error traceback.

Comment: and all of the code (and just to make sure: don't have a file called re.py or requests.py in your working directory)

Comment: The code you've shown here works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera-dl/issues/241) random github issue, you may want to update your requests library to the latest version
ie. `# pip install requests -U`

Comment: Ok I reinstalled the requests package and the error went away. But the results is empty.

Comment: I will ask that in another question

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad first of all, I think you need to get the ```.text``` of your ```.get()``` like ```raw_page = requests.get(yahoo).text```. As for your regex search, I'm not quite sure what's going on there

Comment: I added `.text` as you said but it is still empty. I just want the first 10 search results. My regex code is probably wrong.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad when I ran it locally, raw_page had contents, but I do believe it is the regex that is not returning anything. My bet is that it's something wrong with the ```<``` character, but it could be something else, or multiple things.